# Im trying to upload files using ajax and symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, file-upload

I'm using Symfony 2.7

I got this form

```
<form name="Document" method="post" action enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" id="documento" name="Document[Ruta]" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" onclick="saveDoc()" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Subir</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this ajax:

```
function saveDoc() {
    var inputFile = document.getElementById('documento');
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('doc', file, file.name);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('fileupload') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'data': data},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    });

}
```

with this symfony controller:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->files->get('doc')->getClientOriginalName;
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $filename = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

    $request->files->get('doc')->move(
        $this->getParameter('upload_directory'),
        $filename
    );
    $document = new Document();
    $document->setRuta($filename);
    $document->setIdUser($user);
    $document->setFechaCreacion(new \DateTime("now"));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($document);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(true);

}
```

But I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
>   500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

I saw 235897 pages with file uploading with symfony and ajax, I cannot understand what is wrong in my code, can you guys help me please?

Comment: You're sending the `data` data through the POST request but trying to get the `doc` later in your controller. Try to get your POST data in the controller by calling `$data = $request->request->get('data')` and only then look what you've got in `doc`: `$doc = $data['doc']`

Comment: i tried that, and $data is null

Comment: Check what POST params are you getting by using the other method: `$data = $request-＞request－＞all()`. If you still get null check if you're actually sending the file.

Comment: Okay i get null again, so the problem is the ajax i suppose?

Comment: How do you check your `$data` variable?

Comment: with var_dump($data), the array is empty

Comment: You can only get the contents of the `$data` variable by returning it with `return new JsonResponse($data)` from your controller and then viewing it whether in your browser or in the `ajax` **success** section (assuming you've got no errors). You're not trying to view it by going to the url of your controller, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
function saveDoc() {
    var inputFile = document.getElementById('documento');
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('doc', file, file.name);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('fileupload') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'data': data},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    });

}
```

To

```
function saveDoc() {
    var inputFile = document.getElementById('documento');
    var file = inputFile.files[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('doc', file, file.name);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path('fileupload') }}",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    });

}
```

and in the controller

Change following line:

```
$file = $request->files->get('doc')->getClientOriginalName;
```

to:

```
$file = $request->files->get('doc');
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$file = $request->files->get('doc')->getClientOriginalName;
```

to

```
$file = $request->files->get('doc');
```