# Send a file through AJAX with symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am trying to send a CSV file with an AJAX request en then handle it in a controller.
My problem is I am getting a null file in my controller.

Here is my AJAX request :

```
let csvfile = csvFile.files[0]
var data = new FormData();

data.append('file', csvfile)
// console.log(...data)
$.ajax({
    type        :   'POST',
    url         :   '/template/generateAuto/' + templateId,
    contentType: false,
    processData : false,
    data: data,
    success: function(msg) {console.log(msg)},
});
```

Here is my controller function that should handle the file

```
$file = $request->files->get('file');
return new JsonResponse($file);
```

I here am just trying to debug that's why there's only this part of code in my controller.

I tried dumping the ***$request*** in my controller but I have nothing.

I have already looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738757/im-trying-to-upload-files-using-ajax-and-symfony) but I can't find what I am doing wrong. Since I tried dumping my `$request`and it is empty.
Also, doing a `console.log(...data)` outputs this :

```
0 "file"
1 File {name: "template74.csv", lastModified: 1651136688000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 200, type: "text/csv", …}
```

So my file is in my FormData.

Comment: can you `console.log(data);`

Comment: @geertjanknapen `console.log(data)`gives me `FormData {append: function, delete: function, get: function, getAll: function, has: function, …}`. `console.log(...data)`gives me `"file"
1 File {name: "template74.csv", lastModified: 1651136688000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 200, type: "text/csv", …}`